# Could not tell user that item was not deleted in UITableViewDatasource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Recently I am separating model part of my UITableView to UITableViewDataSource implementation (this implementation is separate class). While records of table can be deleted, and deletion has to be done also in REST API. Is there any option how to tell user that record was not deleted, eq. network error happened?

I can do something like this (in implementation of UITableViewDataSource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        let item = getItem(indexPath)
        restApi.delete(item.id, callback: { ok in
            if (ok) {
                tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Deletion was not successfull.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okAction)
                tableView.superview.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        })
    }
}
```

But I don't like that solution - showing alert from model. Is there any standard way to tell that this committing function failed?

Comment: This is showing the alert from the controller, not the model, since it is the controller that implements the data source and delegate methods.

Comment: separate subject but I wouldn't reloadData() on the entire table view. just remove that one item from the table view and that way you can animate its removal.

Comment: assuming your model is a separate class that your controller is using have you looked at doing a protocol? your model could then callback into the controller via the protocol informing it of a successful or unsuccessful delete.

Comment: @dniswhite I have thinking about some protocol, but this scenario (deleting something on remote server with possibility of failure) seems so common to me that I suppose there should be some standard way to do it (like returning some true/false from this method which will indicate what happend). BTW, thank you for idea to delete only one item.